# Magento 2.4.5-p1 cloud have inbuilt GA4 Enhanced Ecommerce module?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-enhanced

I read in some articles as magento 2 commerce cloud had GA4 in built module to support Enhanced commerce. 
If yes, Can you share the official configuration document ? I got this document from devdocs 
"**[https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/marketing/google-tools/google-tag-manager.html**"](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/marketing/google-tools/google-tag-manager.html**%22). 
I downloaded the "GTM_M2_Config.json" file and imported into my google tag manager but the file containes all the events, triggers and variable related to "universal analytics". I want GA4 configuration document same as above.